# Integrating Karma and webstorm

Tags: angularjs, webstorm, karma-runner

I would like to integrate Karma and webstorm for windows, I have followed the steps from this web:
http://mobicon.tistory.com/273 (translate it to english) but does not work.

I have created one Karma Server and a Karma run:

In Path to Node Js File textfield, I have pointed to a karma file from the node-modules:

C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\karma\0.8.4\package\bin\karma

In the application parameters for the server start and for the Karma Run run

I get the following errors:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'optimist'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Javito\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\karma\0.8.4\package\lib\cli.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Hello! Karma support is under construction, it is planned for WebStorem 7 (see http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-645)

Comment: BTW, have you tried the tutorial available [here](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/index.html)?

Comment: Hi lena, I took a look on the video, but it was for mac and also for Testacular not for Karma, thanks anyway!

Comment: One of our developers just created a [blog post](http://www.vonlay.com/blog/webstorm) on this exact topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was the Karma execution file (Path to node App JS file) I was pointing to, here is my configuration for both server and run:

Karma Server:

[image: Karma server config]

Karma Run:

[image: Karma Run config]

Comment: Thanks! Was having the same issue tonight with getting karma running with pycharm.

Answer (score -1):

Trying to run sails app(app.js nodejs) in Webstorm gave me the optimist error in Ubuntu 14(32 bits).  I fixed it by running:

> sudo npm install optimist

Cheers!